# Rewrite Python project to Java - worth it?

Tags: java, python, performance, optimization

First of all, I love Python, and I currently use it for most stuff. However, as a PhD student, I mostly implement prototypes for testing and evaluating ideas. This also includes that I'm usually the only one coding, and that -- while I certainly try to write half-way efficient code -- performance is not a primary issue. And for quick prototyping, Python is for me just neat.

Now I consider to go with some of my stuff more "serious", i.e., to bring it into a productive environment, make it better maintainable, and maybe more efficient. So I wonder if it's worthy to rewrite my code to, say, Java (with which I'm also reasonably familiar). I know that Python is not slow, but things like Java's static typing including seems to make it less prone to errors on a larger scale, particularly when different people work on the same project.

Comment: This is subjective. It might be better on programmers.

Comment: IMHO, if you're *only* doing it to gain the benefits of static typing, your time would be better spent writing unit tests, improving robustness of your current codebase, improving documentation and educating your fellow programmers.

Comment: This depends on your project. Typically, python should be better since it calls significant amount of C stuff on the back end. However, python also makes your code simpler and easier to read.

Comment: there's type hints in python3, btw.

Comment: @Harry: High subjectivity is not a criteria for posting on Programmers.  If anything, Programmers is as strict as Stack Overflow is, so you can't use subjectivity as a criteria for determining topicality there.  Read http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @RobertHarvey I thought it was more open to discussion than stackoverflow. This question could be read as Python is for weenies ie this line `Now I consider to go with some of my stuff more "serious", i.e., to bring it into a productive environment,` makes it sound like Python is in some way inferior to Java for production.

Comment: @Harry, sorry for my phrasing! It was certainly not my intention to belittle Python and even less so Python programmers. In contrast, as I said, I love Python, and I don't even dare to call myself a programmer. Hence, my question. My main thinking is probably that Java would automatically "force" me to code a bit more careful. So, as others commented, it boils down to a lot of subjectivity.

Comment: @Christian The only language I've used that seemed to be forcing me to be careful was Haskell. I still managed to write really sloppy code in it. I don't think Java will make you any more careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only worth it if it solves a real problem, note, that problem could be

1. I want to learn something better
2. I need it to go faster to reduce power requirements in my colo.
3. I need to hire more people and the talent pool for [insert language here]
   is too small.
4. Insert innumerable real problems here.

Python and Java are both suitable for production. Write it in whatever makes it easiest to solve the problems you and or your team are facing and if you want to preempt some problems make sure you've done your homework. Plenty of projects have died because they chose C/C++ believing performance was going to be a major factor without thinking about the extra effort involved in using these language well.

You mentioned maintainability. You're likely to require more code to rewrite it in Java and there's a direct correlation between Bugs and LOC. It's up for debate which one is easier to maintain. I'm sure both camps believe theirs is.

Of the two which one do you enjoy coding with the most?

Comment: all valid points, thanks! I just fear that Python gives me too much freedom. For example, if I think that method should return an additional value, I just ad it to the return statement. Or if a method needs occasionally an additional input parameter, I just add it to the method head with a default value so usage of the method is not affected. But, yeah, all this would fall under your comment that I need to do my homework.

Comment: The flexibility you're describing ie the freedom if used correctly can actually lead to very robust systems. It's not uncommon to encounter C structs that have been padded because some version in the future may require it ie they may need to return extra data. Python is a wonderful language, use it, abuse it and when you hit performance issues start looking at options ie C functions etc. Java is also a wonderful language and the same things apply. Try and use the one that when you wake up you smile and look forward to using it.

Answer (score 1):

The crucial question is this one: "Java's static typing including seems to make it less prone to errors on a larger scale".  The crucial word here is "seems."  Sure, Java will help you catch this one particular type of error.  But how important is that, and what do you have to pay for it?  The overhead imposed by Java's type system means that you have to write more lines of code, which means reduced productivity.  I've used both and I have no doubt that I'm more productive in Python.  I have found that type-related bugs in Python are generally easy to find and fix.  Keep in mind that in a professional environment you're not going to ship code without testing it pretty carefully.  The bottom line for a programming environment is *productivity* - usable functionality per unit of effort, not the number of bugs you found and fixed during development.

My advice: if you have a working project written in Python, don't rewrite it unless you're certain there's a benefit.

Comment: can't argue with that. I'm certainly faster with Python. However, I feel that Python sometimes makes me a bit sloppy, e.g., by allowing to return multiple output or defining optional input values. Obviously, that's my problem and not the of Python :). Hence, my question if there might be some more tangible reasons to go from Python to Java. Since there are not, I will most likely stick to it, but refactor, improve and test my code.

Comment: @Christian OK but beware of holding onto Java-based biases.  Good style in Java isn't the same as good style in Python.  You can use Python to write programs in the style of Java (for that matter you can use Python to write program in the style of Fortran) but you're giving up some of Python's power if you do.

Answer (score 0):

Java is inherently object oriented. Alternatively python is procedural.

As far as the ability of the language to handle large projects you can make do with either.

As far as producing more usable products I would recommend java script as opposed to java because of its viability in the browser. By embedding your js in a publicly hosted website you allow people with no coding knowledge to run your project seamlessly in the browser.

Further more all the GUI design features of HTML are available at your disposal.

That said any language has it's ups and downs and anything I've said here is simply my perception.

Comment: It might be more accurate to say that Java is *strictly* object oriented, while Python is not.  To say that a well-written object-oriented Python program has any less *object-orientedness* than a Java program is simply not true.

Comment: @kpie: I'm actually not talking about Web development.

Comment: Development is development, web is a feature.